# C++ extractor (>>) overload not reading and assigning Matrix class

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, overloading, private

For school we are supposed to take the teacher's main function and build the implementation around it; his file opens a file as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
ifstream infile;
string infilename;
Matrix w;
infile.open(argv[1]);
    if(!infile.is_open()) {
        cerr << "ERROR opening input file " << argv[1] << endl;
        cerr << "Usage: Prog1 <input file name> <output file name>\n";
        return(0);
        }
infile >> w;
```

Where we are supposed to define the Matrix class as:

```
class Matrix{
private:
    //these are given and not allowed to change
    double tl;
    double tr;
    double bl;
    double br;
public:


    //this is all me, 

    Matrix(); //basic constructor
    Matrix(double intl, double intr, double inbl, double inbr); // advanced constructor
    void print();
    void assign(double intl, double intr, double inbl, double inbr); //

    friend Matrix operator+(const Matrix& x, const Matrix& y);
    friend Matrix operator-(const Matrix& x, const Matrix& y);
    friend Matrix operator*(const Matrix& x, const Matrix& y);
    friend Matrix operator/(const Matrix& x, const Matrix& y);

    Matrix& operator=(const Matrix& matrix);
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, const Matrix& y);

    //PROBLEM AREA? ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
    friend istream& operator>> (istream &in, Matrix w);

protected:

};
```

so when it comes time to read the input file, how am I supposed to read the numbers into the w from main? what I have now is:

```
istream& operator >> (istream &in, Matrix w){
    in >> w.tl >> w.tr >> w.bl >> w.br;
    cout << w;
    return in;
}
```

this generates errors as it stands because w.tl is private, and I tested it when it was public, and it still wasn't reading anything. I tested just reading the numbers into normal double values, and those read just fine, but I have to read and assign inline using the >> operator, which has to return &in, so I can't use the .assign() function to put the doubles i read into a Matrix, and pass that matrix back to main.

How do I approach this? is it possible to overload the >> operator to do what my professor is asking?

Comment: SHouldn't `Matrix w` be `Matrix & w` in definition of `operator>>`?

Comment: You solved it! Thank you, I can't believe I missed that. add it as an answer so I can give you the proper points

Comment: Glad I could help. I made the proper answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reference is missing i.e. `Matrix w` should be `Matrix & w`:

Instead of this:

```
 istream& operator>> (istream &in, Matrix w);
```

you should have:

```
 istream& operator>> (istream &in, Matrix & w);
```

Glad I could help.